# PHP - Add a method to a class

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl

I'm looking for a way to extend a PHP class to add a custom method. In particular I want to add a date-format method to MongoDate (from the PHP MongoDB driver).

I just thought it would be much cleaner, if the MongoDate object received from a Mongo collectio, provides a method to make it readable, and not having the need to call a function or class to do that.

```
$d = new MongoDate();

some_date_format($d); // the way it works now

$d->format(); // the way it would be cleaner
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Read up on [php object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) :-)

Comment: Same here, I want the object received from `MongoCollection::find();` to be affected as well. Does it work if i just cast the MongoDate received from find to my new class?

Comment: The adapter pattern may be more appropriate here. Check it out: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdapterPattern

Comment: Thanks, this pattern looks good for this purpose. But I thougt, as PHP is so dynamic, there would be a way to add a new method (I guess C++ can do that, I'm not sure anymore)

Comment: I've just found http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php but I guess it's a bad Idea, the last release of the runkit PECL was 2006. I'll still give it a try!

Comment: Ok, doesn't work `Warning: runkit_method_add() [function.runkit-method-add]: class mongodate is not a user-defined class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inherit from it!

```
class myClass extends MongoDate{
    public function format(){
    }
}
```

Then just implement it:

```
$d = new myClass ();

some_date_format($d); // the way it works now

$d->format(); // the way it would be cleaner
```

Comment: I thought about it, but this wouldn't affect the object I receive from `MongoCollection::find();`

Comment: @PhilippSpieß you should really put what you tried and how it came out in your question. That way peoples will know how to help you better. That being said please post the real code and we'll have a look at it and help.

Comment: @Truth indeed! fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippSpieß: short of creating a `Decorator`, this is just how it works.... If only `Mongo` had methods to override classes like `PDO`'s `setAttribute(PDO_STATEMENT_CLASS,'someClassExtendingPDOStatement')`.... BUt unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Extend it. It's a basic OOP principle.

```
class NewClass extends MongoDate {
    public function newFunction(){
        //Stuff here.
    }
}
```

This will define a new class `NewClass` which will inherit all public and protected properties and methods from the old `MongoDate` class, and will also have the `newFunction()` function included.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change what type the PHP driver returns for dates, so lznogood & Truth's answer is the best you can do.